# Fanfiction where Harry goes to where his mother grew up, is taken in by Snape, and has infected welts on his back

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry goes to see where his mother lived as a child. He gets drunk and ends up in a tree that Snape and Lily used to go to. A ward tells Snape someone is there, and he finds Harry. Harry ends up staying at Snape's. Harry gets sick due to an infection in his back, and Snape has to lance open the welts and bandage them and pack them. He also tries to run away to Grimmauld Place.

During his stay, Harry accidentally breaks a glass, cutting open his hand. The bedrooms are hidden by a bookshelf.

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: while the answer makes this question seem like a story identification question we do not edit questions based off from the answer they get. the question should be formatted to stand alone without answers as such i'm voting to close as unclear

Comment: I agree that it isn't necessarily a question, but it is clear from context that OP was asking about a story identification

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your description sounds like [*The Definition of Home*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5878880/1/The-Definition-of-Home) by Oliver.snape, but no where in that story does Harry get sick from an infection.

The original querent has clarified that the infected back comes from [Chapter 12](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/6984029/12/Last-Will-and-Testament-of-Lily-Evans-Potter) of *Last Will and Testament of Lily Evans Potter*.

Comment: thank you you are right the definition of home is the one. the part where I got the back infection came from lillys last will and testament. so sorry I got it jumbled because I read both them at the same time and it has been awhile since I read them so they got a little mixed up. thank you for your help :)

Comment: yes sorry I am asking story identification.

Comment: @hyten: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. :) Congratulations on finding it.